# Prioritize local variables in Visual Studio Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Is it possible to configure Intellisense to prioritize local variables suggestions over class types?
For example if I declare `httpContext` variable I want to get this variable suggestion on top instead of `HttpContext` class type.
[Example situation screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lf8B.png)

--- Edit ---

Providing additional example to distinct `httpcontent` behavior from `httpContent`.

[Different behavior for `httpcontent` and `httpContent` from the other PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7xAv.gif)

Comment: What your VS version? It is quite a abnormal behavior and VS Intellisense will prioritize local variables suggestions by default. In my side, it works well. Please try my below suggestions to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure Intellisense to prioritize local variables
>   suggestions over class types? For example if I declare httpContext
>   variable I want to get this variable suggestion on top instead of
>   HttpContext class type.

This is quite a abnormal behavior. **In fact**, Visual Studio Intellisense will prioritize local variables rather than class types by default. And in my side, it works perfectly. See this:

[image]

**So** I think there are some environmental factors that cause this error. Please try these suggestions:

1. close your VS Instance, delete .vs hidden folder, bin, obj folder. And then restart your project again to test it.
2. clean vs component caches-----delete files under `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx(16.0 is VS2019,15.0 is VS2017)\ComponentModelCache`
3. disable any third party extensions or just use [denvenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start VS to test your project in case some other extensions cause this abnormal behavior.
4. [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS Installer
5. if your VS is not the latest version, please try to update it in case there are some fixes.

**Update 1**

After researching more detailed info provided by you, l find that this should be an issue in visual studio intellisense and in fact, l faced the same issue as you described.

So l have reported this issue on our **DC Forum**.See [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958890/top-priority-local-variables-cannot-be-focused-in.html). You can vote it and comment any detailed info which can raise the team's attention.

Since the process may be a bit long, as a suggestion, you can use the [resharper extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzrfrjZuw6AIVTAwrCh0hxwCGEAAYASAAEgLV-fD_BwE) which works successfully without this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I followed your steps except 4. and they didn't help. Before I proceed with 4. I would like to be sure we are on the same page as your example is a bit different than mine. It works for me exactly as you showed in your example as long as variable is named `httpcontent` and not `httpContent`. Could you please try with `httpContent`? Please check the gif I have just attached to the original question. It clrearly shows that `HttpContext` is suggested when I would prefer `httpContent` to be suggested after I wrote `httpcont`.

Comment: I felt that something has changed as I don't remember having this issue before. Thanks for double checking :)
I reposted my gif there and voted for the thread. Fingers crossed.